# Where did I go wrong with this Integral?

Tags: trigonometric-integrals

My integral is $$\int \frac{dx}{x \sqrt{3-x^2}}$$

so I used trig substitution,

let $x$ = $\sqrt{3}\cos{\theta}$

let $dx$ = $-\sqrt{3}\sin{\theta}\ d\theta$

$$\int \frac{-\sqrt{3}\sin{\theta}\ d\theta}{\sqrt{3}\cos{\theta}\sqrt{3-(\sqrt{3}\cos{\theta})^2}}$$

$$ =-\int \frac{\sin{\theta}\ d\theta}{\cos{\theta}\sqrt{3(1-\cos^2{\theta})}}$$
 $$=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{3}} \int \frac{\sin{\theta}\ d\theta}{\cos{\theta}\sin{\theta}}$$
 $$=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{3}} \int \sec{\theta}\ d\theta$$
 $$=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{3}} \log{\left(\tan{\theta}+\sec{\theta}\right)} + C$$

Next I converted $\theta$ back into x using the triangle. If $\cos{\theta} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{3}}$ then side $a$ of the triangle = $x$ and side $c = \sqrt{3}$. The missing side, $b$, is $\sqrt{3-x^2}$.

$\tan\theta = \frac{b}a = \frac{\sqrt{3-x^2}}{x}$

$\sec\theta = \frac{1}{\cos\theta} =\frac{\sqrt{3}}{x}$.

Substituted back in my answer is

$$-\frac{1}{\sqrt3} \log\left( \frac{\sqrt{3-x^2}}{x} +\frac{\sqrt{3}}{x}\right)+C$$

but it is incorrect. I checked Wolfram Alpha and it returned

$$ \frac{\log{x} -\log{ \left(\sqrt{9-3x^2}+3 \right)}}{\sqrt3}+C$$

sometimes Wolfram Alpha returns an equivalent answer, just written in different terms, so I briefly plotted both equations [here in Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gmgodryp12) to check if they were equal, but unfortunately, they are not equivalent, although they are close. I've been trying this problem for over an hour and I can't figure out what went wrong. Can anyone show me what to do?

Comment: They are equivalent, they differ by a constant.

Comment: Answer confirmed by *Mathematica*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong. Factor out a $\sqrt 3$ from their (second) log term, and absorb it into the constant of integration. Remember, also, that $\log(a/b) = \log a - \log b$.